# I am translating canvas in android but after translation it goes to its initial state.How can I stop it to translated state

Tags: android, canvas, graphics

My code is here

int x= 0, y=0;

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

    if(x <=  -OFFSETX ){
        c.translate(x , y);
        x++;
        y--;

    }
    // other drawing stuff
    invalidate();
}
```

Thanks in advance for solution

Comment: you need to translate it every time `onDraw` method is called

Comment: Is there any way that i will traslate it once

Comment: no, there is no such way, what is a problem with calling `Canvas#translate` ?

Comment: What about the coordinates of other views like buttons

Comment: what coordinates? what do you mean?